# About a remark in Evans PDE, in the regularity of elliptic equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-equations

On Page 341, after Theorem 5 (Higher boundary regularity) in Chapter 6.3 (Regularity), Evans states that

> Remark. If $u$ is the unique solution of $$
> \left\{\begin{aligned}
> L u=f & \text { in } U \\
> u=0 & \text { on } \partial U
> \end{aligned}\right.
> $$
> then estimate
> $$
> \|u\|_{H^{m+2}(U)} \leq C\left(\|f\|_{H^{m}(U)}+\|u\|_{L^{2}(U)}\right),
> $$
> simplifies to read
> $$
> \|u\|_{H^{m+2}(U)} \leq C\|f\|_{H^{m}(U)} .
> $$

I don't understand why uniqueness of solution can eliminate $\|u\|_{L^{2}(U)}$ on the right hand side.

Comment: Theorem 6 in section 6.2

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks!